# How do I move a window past the screen edge

Tags: window

I am using one screen and am trying to do 2 things at once. I am watching netflix and playing runescape. In windows I could move the application to only show half the game window(Runescape client)
In ubuntu It does not let me move the game window past the edge of the screen. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

In versions  prior to 18,the simplest way to do this is to set Workspace Switcher: System Settings > Behaviour tab

[image]

This will allow screens to 'wrap' into the adjacent workspace.

In version 18:

[image]

To use workspaces, click Activities on above the vertical bar (dock), then move your move to the right of your screen to show the workspaces in used plus one empty one.

You can then move apps from one workspace to another by simply dragging and dropping the apps onto the other workspace. This workspace now contains the apps you have dropped, and a new empty workspace appears at the bottom of the workspace selector.

(for version 18, acknowledgements to https://websiteforstudents.com/what-are-workspaces-and-how-to-use-them-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/)

Comment: Can't find these settings in the latest ubuntu version

Comment: @RuskiCode might well have helped your cause if you mentioned which version you were using in the first place. That way people can offer better quality answers.